# Security flaw between UserStore and Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to override the UserStore for my ASP.NET MVC 5 project because I use a Web API 2 to handle all the data.

It works fine but I have a major security flaw in my API. I can't make the function that returns a user `[autorize]`. So anyone can call it with any username and steal all the user's information.

Here's the API function in my `UserController`.

```
        [Route("api/users/user/{username}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUserByUserName(string username)
        {
            username = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(username);
            AspNetUser result = unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();

            //If the user doesn't exist
            if (result == null)
            {
                //throw NotFound("Could not find username: " + username);
                return NotFound();
            } 

            //Create the user to return
            User user = CreateUserFromEntity(result);
            return Ok(user);
        }
```

It all starts here when a user try to log in.

This function

```
await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

calls my UserStore to get a user by a username then after it verifies that the password is good. Then it returns a user if the credentials are good and `null` is something is wrong. But I don't have access to the UserManager code.

```
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.Resources.InvalidCredentials);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

So in my `UserStore` I have to implement this function

All I have is a username and it needs to return a `ApplicationUser`. So the client doesn't have a token for the API and it asks for all the user's information.  At least if I had a username and a password, I wouldn't mind if the API wasn't `[authorize]`.

```
        public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
        {
            return Task<ApplicationUser>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //Retrieves the API Url from the web config
                String uri = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiURL"];

                //Set the api 
                Api api = new Api(uri);
                HttpResponseMessage response = api.HttpGet("api/users/user/" + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(userName));

                ApplicationUser ap = new ApplicationUser();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Parse the response body. Blocking!
                    var user = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<User>().Result;

                    //Set the application user with the response
                    ap.Id = user.Id;
                    ap.UserName = user.UserName;
                    ap.PasswordHash = user.Password;

                }
                else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    //The username doesn't exist.
                    ap = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("The response is not valid. Code: " + response.StatusCode + " Message: " + response.RequestMessage);
                }

                //Return the application user
                return ap;
            });
        }
```

I'm stuck, I don't know how I should manage this. Do I have to create an identity for the client application and call the API with its token? I just have a feeling that something is wrong. I think it would be better to send the username and the password to the API and let it manages the credentials verification but the `UserStore` doesn't have the password.

What's the proper way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: If my question is not clear, I can edit it